# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im trying to get values from foreign table.

```
{{Auth::user()->stat()->dexterity}}
```

This is my user model:

```
public function stat()
{
   $this->hasMany('App\Stat', 'user_id');
}
```

This is my stat model:

```
public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
}
```

Im getting this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Can someone help ?

All values exists in DB

SOLVED.
I forget too add `return` in both functions before `$this`

Comment: Divide and conquer in debugging: Divide the offending line in the different components that compose it to check which part is failing

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an attribute from a non-object or a null variable.
The other thing is that `hasMany` methods return Collections through attribute calls.
So, you should try something like this:

```
@foreach (\Auth::user()->stat as $stat)
    {{$stat->dexterity}}
@endforeach
```

But, you should be aware that if no user is logged in, the same error will be thrown.